# CMF bundle breaking Doctrine? Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, doctrine, content-management-system

This is the first time I have used the CMF for Symfony2 with the SimpleCmsBundle and I am having a lot of difficulty setting it up correctly. The main issue I seem to have is the fact that Doctrine is breaking when I clear the cache:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent parameter "Could not determine the
>   Doctrine manager. Either Doctrine is not configured or a bundle i   s
>   misconfigured.".

When I comment out my CMF bundle includes, I do not get this error. Here is my config:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

knp_menu:
    twig: true

cmf_core:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

        # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
        #sonata.media.block.media:
        #sonata.media.block.gallery:
        #sonata.media.block.feature_media:

        # Some block with different templates
        #acme.demo.block.demo:
        #    templates:
        #       - { name: 'Simple', template: 'AcmeDemoBundle:Block:demo_simple.html.twig' }
        #       - { name: 'Big',    template: 'AcmeDemoBundle:Block:demo_big.html.twig' }
```

My `AppKernel.php` file:

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\CmfRoutingBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\CmfCoreBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle\CmfMenuBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ContentBundle\CmfContentBundle(),

    // Dependencies of the CmfMenuBundle
    new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

    // Dependencies of the CmfBlockBundle
    new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
    new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle()
);
```

As far as I am aware, I've added the minimum required configuration, but I must be missing something otherwise it surely would not affect Doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Symfony CMF Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/standard-edition/), you're most likely missing the inclusion of the [DoctrinePHPCRBundle in your AppKernel](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/standard-edition/blob/master/app/AppKernel.php#L22):

```
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Doctrine\Bundle\PHPCRBundle\DoctrinePHPCRBundle(),
    );
```

and the relevant [doctrine_phpcr configuration](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/standard-edition/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L68):

```
    # app/config/config.yml
    doctrine_phpcr:
        odm: ~
```

Comment: I believe this was partly it, but I think my parameters needed tweaking so I could create the config correctly. I ended up re-installing my Symfony project and got it working now with the PHPCRBundle, thanks!